# Fix menu on the background image position

Tags: menu, responsive-design, background-image

**It's my problem:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/Vqa7v/**

```
body {
background: url("http://imgs.ir/imgs/201307/1336_menu.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}

#menu {
display: block;
height: 193px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
top: 32px;
width: 400px;
}

nav {
left: 0;
min-width: 426px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 79px;
}

nav a {
padding: 5px 7px;
color:white;
}

<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#">BLOG</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

At first, the menu is fit to background position, but make the *Result* window smaller & smaller to see when the menu get out of the background position.

How to avoid that and fix menu to background image position? (I want to have a menu in center of my website on its background image)

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/qZHnb/

Comment: No I don't want the menu break, I just want it behave like an image. The result should be this: http://jsfiddle.net/c4aB7/

Answer (score 0):

Had some real trouble understanding what you were looking for, but is this it? Basically it needed a whole bunch of changes that I've made to `nav` etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/robsterlini/Vqa7v/2/

Comment: Sorry, no it isn't. I do that by my self and posted as an answer. Thank you Rob.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my self: http://jsfiddle.net/Vqa7v/4/

```
.menu {
position:absolute;
top: 20px;
left:15px;
}

nav {
text-align: center;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:url('http://upload7.ir/images/27569577012963327319.jpg') no-repeat;
min-width:500px;
}

nav a {
padding:0 5px 0 0;
line-height:35px;
color:oldlace;
text-shadow:0 0 2px #000;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing:1px;
}

<nav>
       <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#">BLOG</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
       </div>
</nav>
```

Small the RESULT window width and see the menu is fixed to the background image.

Comment: Really stop using absolute positioning like that. It'll cause havoc later on in your project. Glad you sorted out what you wanted. Still have no idea what it was that you were trying to fix, but good on you.

Comment: It's a simple 404 page, so I'm not worry about future. But I will become happy to hear if you have any other solution. I think it can describe you my problem completely: http://imgs.ir/imgs/201308/Untitled-1.jpg

Comment: So you want your page to break on small screens? Meh, looks like I don't have an answer for it. Good luck.